# Put Links folder replacing Quick Access

Tags: windows, windows-10

Windows 7 had a great feature, the Links on the left side of Windows Explorer. Using the Links folder we could rename the shortcuts. When Microsoft introduced the Quick Access, if you rename a shortcut, it will rename the folder. I don't want that.

Does anyone know how to bring back the Links(Favorites) back replacing the Quick Access?

Answer (score 2):

I think that your post is wrongly labelled "Windows 7".
My answer below assumes that you are on Windows 10 and would like to return
to the navigation pane of Explorer the item of Favorites and perhaps remove
Quick Access.

Below is a method for returning the Favorites folder to the Quick Access pane.

**Add or delete the Favorites folder**

To add, create and execute the following `.reg` file :

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{323CA680-C24D-4099-B94D-446DD2D7249E}]
@="Favorites"
"SortOrderIndex"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{323CA680-C24D-4099-B94D-446DD2D7249E}]
"SortOrderIndex"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\{323CA680-C24D-4099-B94D-446DD2D7249E}]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel]
"{323CA680-C24D-4099-B94D-446DD2D7249E}"=dword:00000001
```

To remove :

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{323CA680-C24D-4099-B94D-446DD2D7249E}]

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\{323CA680-C24D-4099-B94D-446DD2D7249E}]


[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace\{323CA680-C24D-4099-B94D-446DD2D7249E}]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel]
"{323CA680-C24D-4099-B94D-446DD2D7249E}"=-
```

**Add or delete the Quick Access folder**

To remove :

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer]
"HubMode"=dword:00000001
```

To add back :

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer]
"HubMode"=dword:00000000
```

Comment: Nice! Where can I find this kind of information?

Comment: I have constructed the answer from multiple sources, for example [link](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/35873-add-remove-favorites-navigation-pane-windows-10-a.html). You may google for them.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Has anybody figured out how to make this node be able to expand to show shortcuts under it in the left pane yet though? Unfortunately, adding it back loses a lot of its value if it won't show shortcut items under it in the left pane (yes it shows them in the right pane when the node is selected but still, to be able to replace QA it needs to be able to show them when expanded in the left pane).